# Search rows with the same ID and apply AND filter to count a particular occurrence

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm fairly new with PowerBi and DAX, and have now run into a small issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Suppose i have the following table:

```
  ID  Type
+---+-------+
| 1 | type1 |
+---+-------+
| 1 | type2 |
+---+-------+
| 1 | type1 |
+---+-------+
| 1 | type4 |
+---+-------+
| 2 | type1 |
+---+-------+
| 2 | type1 |
+---+-------+
| 2 | type1 |
+---+-------+
```

In my task, I want to be able to count how many of my IDs that have changed type from `type1` to `type2`.
In the following case, ID = 1 is the only entity which change its type.

My initial idea was to do a measure with the correpsonding DAX code:

```
Measure = Calculate(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID]), 
    FILTER('Table' AND 'Table'[Type] = "type1" && 'Table'[Type] = "type2"))
```

The above does however return "null". The rationale behind the following was the thought that I could count the distinct IDs where the corresponding type had changed from `type1` to `type2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be what you are trying to do.

```
Count IDs With Type1 And Type2
= COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        /* Distinct values of IDs */
        VALUES ( Table1[ID] ),
        /* Keep only IDs which contains both type1 and type2 */
        VAR _Types = CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Table1[Type] ) )
        RETURN
            CONTAINS ( _Types, Table1[Type], "type1" )
            && CONTAINS ( _Types, Table1[Type], "type2" )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need OR (`||`) , not AND (`&&`).

Count all items where the type is either type1 or type2.

AND is impossible.

Also, you have a syntax error in your DAX. Your formula should be

```
Measure = Calculate(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID]), 
    FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Type] = "type1" || 'Table'[Type] = "type2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, what you have done is, counting the IDs where the status have been either `type1` or `type2` - Meaning that ID = 2, gets counted even though it doesn't have a status of `type2`. I need to get the IDs where the status has been both one and two at some point in time.That is, it should only count the IDs where the status has been `type1` and `type2`.